# PHP Mysql complicated Order By

Tags: php, mysql

In my sql query

`SELECT unit_price,price_counter FROM products`

It displays the result in a table. The last column of that table is named "Percentage of Price VS Counter". The formula for that column in PHP is as follows:

`$PercentCompare = round((float)(($UnitPrice-$PriceCounter)/$UnitPrice) * 100);`

Now the client is asking that the table is sorted based on that last column. If that column is also a field or column in my `products` table I can easily do a `ORDER BY` but that column is only displayed on the webpage table after using the formula above.

Question is, how can I sort or use `ORDER BY` if that column is a result of a calculation/formula? I am using prepared statement. Do I do:

`SELECT unit_price,price_counter FROM products ORDER BY round((float)((unit_price-price_counter)/unit_price) * 100)` ?

EDIT 2nd ATTEMPT:

```
$InsertCalculation = ", round((float)((unit_price - price_counter)/unit_price) * 100) AS percentagecounter";
$QueryOrderBy = "perc_list_count";
$MyQuery = "SELECT itemid, address, city, state, zipcode, county, nameofowner, unit_price, price_counter, status" . $InsertCalculation . " FROM products WHERE itemid LIKE ? AND address LIKE ? AND city LIKE ? AND state LIKE ? AND zipcode LIKE ? AND county LIKE ? ORDER BY " . $QueryOrderBy . " ASC";
```

Comment: Try `SELECT unit_price,price_counter, round((float)((unit_price-price_counter)/unit_price) * 100) AS percentCompare FROM products ORDER BY  percentCompare` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate and then make order by. something like this

```
SELECT unit_price,price_counter,
  ROUND(((unit_price-price_counter)/unit_price) * 100) as percentage_price
FROM products
ORDER BY percentage_price ASC
```

Here you can calculate `percentage_price` and then make it order by

Comment: You should add the round() too

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it makes the result table go blank :( I edited the post above to show you what I have exactly

Comment: my 2nd attempt is under `EDIT 2nd ATTEMPT`